# What is a misreading error called?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Merriam Webster defines typo as an error (as of spelling) in typed or typeset material.

What is a misreading error called? Seeo? For example, I misread *chuck* as *chunk*.

Comment: 'Typo' is a shortening of 'typographical error' (a mistake made during the process of typing, especially one caused by a slip of the fingers). I don't think there is a similar shortening of 'reading error'.

Comment: Misreading can be used as a noun. No need to add "error" after it.  See [misreading](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misreading).  e.g. He though it said "chuck", but this was a misreading.

Comment: I've been known to call them "thinko" or "braino".

Comment: How could there be a problem with calling that either a 'misread(ing)' or simply a 'mistake'?

Comment: I've heard them called a "speako", which is really leaning into the analogy with "typo", but it is not at all a common term, and every time I've seen it, it was said with a wink, acknowledging that it's a bit of a joke.

Answer (score 5):

*Misreading* or *misread* are acceptable terms for this.:

> Any case of suspected misread loses A (and B) marks on that part, but can gain the M marks.

"Seebo" would not be understood (it's not a word).

Comment: Neither Cambridge nor Webster's carry a noun definition for 'misread' so I would be very hesitant to follow this advice.

Comment: No "misread" as a verb, and "misreading" as a participle (that could head an NP)

Comment: Your example sentence seems to be using "misread" as a noun.

Comment: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/misreading_n

Comment: @JamesK Right, so "a case of misread" would be wrong. It's not natural to say "a case of [verb]". We say things like "*a case of wrongdoing*", where 'wrongdoing' is a noun - the name of a kind of action. Have you ever heard of somebody call it "*wrongdo*"?

Answer (score 4):

There are some nouns, but some aren't nearly as common as 'typo', and they aren't necessarily specific to *reading*.

- A *gaffe* is any unintentional act or remark. It is often used to describe mistakes when reading out loud (such as when a newsreader misreads their autocue). But it also implies that some embarrassment occurred, so may not apply if you were not reading out loud unless perhaps you later made an error from acting on your misreading.
- A *mondegreen* is a misheard phrase, but especially applies to song lyrics.
- An *eggcorn* is a commonly misused phrase that arises from a mishearing, especially one that fundamentally changes the meaning. It is sometimes used for the written word but implies that it has been written incorrectly following a mishearing from the author.

In the absence of a noun, you could just say "*reading error*", given that 'typo' is short for typographical error.

Comment: Yes, but that helps how?